# CS8321: The local function 'TextChange' is declared but never used

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

please help me

```
public Text changingText;

int Cash = '0';
int CashMulti = '1';
int CashPerClick = '1';

public void OnMouseDown()
{
    Cash = Cash + CashPerClick * CashMulti;
    void TextChange()
    {
        changingText.text = "Cash";
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a method within a method, and you're not using the inner method. What's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function should be declared outside the other function and then you can call it whenever you want.

```
public void OnMouseDown()
{
    Cash = Cash + CashPerClick * CashMulti;
    TextChange();
}

void TextChange()
{
    changingText.text = "Cash";
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate people like you who's taking their time to help people who needs it, have a great day! :)